# How to select multiple media files for a widget form?

Tags: widgets, media, media-library

I'm putting a media player in a custom theme I'm writing for a musician. I'd like to execute the `[playlist]` shortcode in a widget area, so this player isn't tied to a specific page or post.

Once I have the attachment IDs in their chosen order, e.g. an array, I can generate the markup. But how can I write a widget form that uses the Media Library to select a set of files?

Comment: I think you need to edit slimjetpack plugin because this may affect plugin default functionality